# Reduced audio volume after upgrading W8 -> W10

Tags: audio, windows-10-upgrade

(*Dislaimer: I'm just a software developer. That causes ppl to think I'm THE computer guy that can solve their issues, so I get asked for help and I'm too friendly to deny...*)

A friend came along with their computer asking if I could check an issue they were having with the audio output on their HP Pavilion (Product no: D2Z59EA) since it was upgrade from W8 to W10 Home (which I had recommended): suddenly the max. volume of the speakers was lower than before!

(Did I mention I'm a developer? I sweat when I see a screwdriver...)

My first idea was to look at Device Manager and check if there were any conflicts (no), driver updates (no) or other stuff I could do (going through the audio problem wizard) - to no avail. I finally even called HP Support - just to hear that this machine was out of support and they had no experience of it running W10 etc.

As the supporter had mentioned "Realtek" in the call, I visited their site and attempted to download & install "some" old audio driver - just in the vague hope it might complain if it was incompatible and would otherwise help, but that had no effect, so I uninstalled it.

I can't believe we should be the only one fighting with this - is that perhaps a known problem? I would appreciate any suggestions how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Press WINDOWS + R to open the run command, type mmsys.cpl and press ENTER. Click on the audio reproducing device and on the Window that opens see at level or volume sorry my Windows is in Portuguese and check if it is on the max volume. Another suggestion would be to see if there are updated drivers but it looks like you already tried this...

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, the volume was at 76% and changing that to 100% did not have a big effect, unfortunately.